# What is the difference between xrays and ultra violet rays?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

Do they differ in just frequency and wavelenght ? Or there is more about it

Comment: Fundamentally, yes. The difference in frequency and wavelength causes a difference in colour, too.

Comment: "A rose by any other name..."  The history of naming different parts of the EM spectrum is full of odd stuff :-).  BTW, @PhysicistByLogic please identify the "color" of X-rays!

Comment: LOL! My bad. Should've mentioned that that was the case for visible spectra.

Comment: The frequency & Planck's constant makes it a difference in *energy* ($E=h\nu$).

Comment: Yes as metnioned the difference is in wavelength (or equivalently frequency) an as a result of Einstein/Planck fromula ($E=hv$) energy as well

Comment: There is also the issue of how those photons are produced.  It is typically easier (by definition of there being more possible methods) to produce UV than x-ray photons.  So far as I know, the only hard separation between $\gamma$-rays and x-rays that I have seen is defined by their source, not necessarily their wavelength/frequency (i.e., their wavelength/frequency can overlap sometimes, but their sources are fundamentally different).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: usually red, green and blue from soft to hard x-ray bands, at least in astronomy ;) http://chandra.harvard.edu/blog/files/images/xallsky_rosat110.jpg, http://www.xray.mpe.mpg.de/rosat/survey/sxrb/12/rgb_ng.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have various properties that differ, but the differences are quantitative, not qualitative, and there is no sharp boundary. The differences occur because of the difference in frequency. A wave that is a gamma ray in one frame of reference could be an x-ray if observed in a different frame.

An example of their different properties is that gamma rays are more penetrating, and are more likely to undergo Compton scattering rather than the photoelectric effect. The reason x rays and gammas were given different names is that originally nobody knew they were both part of the electromagnetic spectrum. The name "gamma" was simply a label used to classify them by how penetrating they were -- more penetrating than alphas or betas.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes, they are both electromagnetic waves and differ only in frequency.

Slightly longer answer: of course they also differ in all other properties that are a function of frequency: wavelength, energy, momentum.